# selenium button , same class, onclick search with many '

Tags: python, selenium, button, onclick, buttonclick

im trying to click "Attack" button. There are 4 button with same text. There are codes im working on it but i couldnt figgure it out . Can you help me to pick any button which i want. Thanks for help...

Button 1 :

```
<button class="expedition_button awesome-button " onclick="attack(null, '2', 1, 0, '')">Attack</button>
```

Button 2:

```
<button class="expedition_button awesome-button " onclick="attack(null, '2', 2, 0, '')">Attack</button>
```

Button 3:

```
<button class="expedition_button awesome-button " onclick="attack(null, '2', 3, 0, '')">Attack</button>
```

Button 4:

```
<button class="expedition_button awesome-button " onclick="attack(null, '2', 4, 0, '')">Attack</button>
```

**I tried these codes below** :

```
        self.web.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class=expedition_button awesome-button 'Attack'])[3]")
```

Also i wanna learn how can i use any defined data before, instead of class name or button name or id..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the specific button try with class and index OR try with text and index whichever you comfortable.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[text()[contains(.,'Attack')]])[indexval]")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='expedition_button awesome-button '])[indexval]")
```

For Button1:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[text()[contains(.,'Attack')]])[1]")
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@class='expedition_button awesome-button '])[1]")
```

Similarly for Button 2 , 3 & 4 just increase the index value.

Comment: **THANKS !** I think i need to learn use these text,contains,@class etc. Thanks again sir..Its a good example for others and me2

Comment: Could you say mate , how can i call these [1] , [2] or [3]  like [data] ? Because i need to call that 'find_element_by_xpaths with some DEFs. How should i write inside of xpath ? Thanks already..

Comment: See when you have multiple elements with same class name and other attributes are same then you need to add indexes to make unique each element.There are many ways you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that.

```
#You will get all 4 buttons xpath in a list
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[text()[contains(.,'Attack')]]")
#Now Iterate this It will click each button
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
    element.click()
```